# Get SVG out of ImageView

Tags: android, androidsvg

I'm using [AndroidSVG](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/index.html) to dynamically place a signature rendered as an svg, for displaying to an `ImageView`.

Here is my code:

```
SVG svg = SVG.getFromString(singleEmployee.signature);
ImageView image_view = (ImageView) layout_signature.findViewById(R.id.toolboxtalk_signature_svg);
image_view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
image_view.setTag(String.format(Locale.US, "employee_signature%d", x));
Drawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture());
image_view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

My question is, how do I get the `SVG` out of the `ImageView` later in my code execution.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
ViewGroup v1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.job_ticket_form);
ImageView signatureImageView = (ImageView) v1.findViewWithTag("employee_signature1");
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = (PictureDrawable) signatureImageView.getDrawable();
Picture picture = pictureDrawable.getPicture();
Context context = signatureImageView.getContext();
String employeeSigSVGString = null;
try {
      SVG svg = SVG.getFromResource(signatureImageView.getContext(), R.id.toolboxtalk_signature_svg);
      employeeSigSVGString = spinner_value + "|" + svg;
} catch (SVGParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas how to get the `SVG` back out of the `ImageView`?

Comment: you can't. the svg was rendered into a drawable, which cannot be transformed back into an svg. You have to use teh `singleEmployee.signature` field, as it already contains the value you seek

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks! I was hoping for a clean method to extract the svg from the drawable, but what you suggest works.